# How do you force start ubuntu on Macbook Pro

Tags: boot, uefi, macbook-pro

My MacBook stopped running LION OS so i decided to install Ubuntu on it. I followed the steps set out (see below) and got Ubuntu working well for a few days. Then it would not boot past the famous 'Mac white screen startup screen.' (The one with the question mark on a folder) It would intermittently boot to Ubuntu. 
From the white screen- Hard shutdown- power on- white screen; then Hard shutdown- power on- Ubuntu.
Eventually tho it just stopped booting Ubuntu completely.

What is the correct procedure for forcing Mac to boot Ubuntu considering that I have installed it correctly following tested procedures. 
Why did it stop after a few days? perhaps it could to do with the Updating that Ubuntu provides that changed something?

Some Info about my system

- Install version of Ubuntu is 14.10 bootable USB
- MacBookPro Retina 13inch (was running Lion OS)
- New SSD installed before Lion crashed see here [[image: Partitioning on my computer]
- Grub install version (GNU GRUB 0.97)
- EFI boot and extra partitioning table [[image: here]]
- I have a directory called /sys/firmware/efi. I checked this by `/sys/firmware/efi` in terminal. Which I think confirms I am booting in EFI
- Boot order is [[image: at the bottom of terminal]]

This is my install procedure see here [Procedure used to install 14.10](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-linux-macbook-pro/). Please note that I did NOT partition in Lion(Mac OS) as Lion stopped working all together and had to go straight to the MacBook start up screen.

One last thing as I continue to work this out is that I can not change Grub in this 'try ubuntu bootable usb' so I loaded Grub Customizer and have this red flag screen shot which I have not encountered Before [[image: Grub Customizer]]

Moderator. Please let me know If I need more information before you post this question. I have no problem in changing it.

Comment: Holding `ALT` at startup should get you into the Mac's boot menu.

Comment: yes it does. But that does not achieve the required goal.

Comment: So no Ubuntu is shown?

Comment: You can try using `boot-repair`, which you can find on community.ubuntu.com

Comment: Boot Repair installed well. Followed all the steps and proceeded to Repair. I also opted to Upgrade Grub to the latest version in Advanced options but that was all.
Now I have rebooted and I have looked good with No Mac boot menu but computer failed to open 
'EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi - 80'0E' 'Failed to load image' ' Failed to open EFI/BOOT/MokManager.efi - 80'0E' 'Failed to load image' It is now frozen here

Comment: Use the LiveUSB/CD you have to see if you can reinstall GRUB on the partition.

Comment: To clarify, reinstall Grub on my the partition where Ubuntu is currently installed sda5, or sda1 which is the EFI system.

Comment: sda1, since that's where the problem is occurring.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27398/discussion-between-carlos-dunick-and-zacharee1).

Answer (score 0):

The White Folder with a question mark means that your MAC is missing a important boot folder from you OS.

If holding alt does not provide a solution:
You can try to reinstall MAC osx my holding Command + R at start up and letting go when you hear the boot chime. It will boot into internet recovery.

Comment: Reinstalling Mac isn't the goal here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Are you saying that it is necessary to reinstall the Mac OS to get that 'important boot folder' ?  Will this enable be to boot ubuntu? Because i do not want Dual Boot. @Vault108

Comment: @CarlosDunick If you were able to boot for such a long time without Mac installed, it wouldn't make sense that Mac would have an important file.

Comment: Then what are we trying to do. Please be specific. I am able to get into Internet recovery for Mac by simply holding the Option key. all the Mac startup options work including option+R

Answer (score 0):

This is an ancient question, but google finds it and maybe my answer will help someone.

In 2021 the best way I found is this:

Boot from the ubuntu flash drive.
Then:

```bsh
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:rodsmith/refind
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install refind
```

https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html